# How to generate identical series of pseudo-random integers?

Tags: random, clojure

Is there more or less standard solution to generate identical series of pseudo-random integers in Clojure?

I know of three standard functions for randomization: [`rand`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/rand), [`rand-int`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/rand-int), and [`rand-nth`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/rand-nth), but they seem to not provide any way to 'set' their internal state.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generated repeatable random sequences with rand-int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007063/how-to-generated-repeatable-random-sequences-with-rand-int)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't repeatedly generate reproducible random numbers when using a seed in Clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441860/why-doesnt-repeatedly-generate-reproducible-random-numbers-when-using-a-seed-in)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Indeed it seems to be a duplicate, but cited question has no decent answer anyway.

Comment: @jbr, My question does not even mention `*rnd*` or something like that, that question is much more specific.

Comment: @Mark, doesn't Alex's answer provide exactly what you are seeking?

Comment: @jbr, I'm not interested in `clojure.data.generators`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defn randomish [seed]
  (repeatedly
    (let [gen (java.util.Random. seed)]
      (fn [] (.nextInt gen)))))

(take 5 (randomish 10))
;(-1157793070 1913984760 1107254586 1773446580 254270492)

(take 5 (randomish 10))
;(-1157793070 1913984760 1107254586 1773446580 254270492)
```

In `randomish`, `repeatedly`

- captures the function
- that captures the `Random` object
- that holds the mutable internal state
- initialised by `seed`.

Every call to `randomish` produces a new sequence object containing a unique `Random` object. But `Random` objects with the same seed produce identical sequences.

(If the above is mistaken, *please* correct me. The [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441860/why-doesnt-repeatedly-generate-reproducible-random-numbers-when-using-a-seed-in) seems to make heavy going).

*Note*

It might be better, in Clojure, to call `.nextLong` instead of `nextInt`.

---

By request, adapted to deal with an optional (exclusive) limit:

```
(defn randomish
  ([seed]
    (repeatedly
      (let [gen (java.util.Random. seed)]
        (fn [] (.nextInt gen)))))
  ([seed limit]
    (repeatedly
      (let [gen (java.util.Random. seed)]
        (fn [] (.nextInt gen limit))))))
```

... producing

```
(take 5 (randomish 10 100))
;(13 80 93 90 46)

(take 5 (randomish 10 100))
;(13 80 93 90 46)
```

Comment: Great answer! It is baffling something like this is not part of the standard clojure library

Comment: @Ezequiel Thanks. I wouldn't be surprised if this is how Haskell does it. A sequence is a good model of a random number generator. And if you can plug in the randomness like this, you can test the thing it drives separately and properly.

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to add for anyone still looking, that there is library on clojars that does this since 2015: https://github.com/trystan/random-seed